# How should I have API users send their keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, security, hash

I'm building an API in NodeJS and an SDK for people who want to use the API to make requests to it. When someone wants to make a request, they have to pass an API key to the method they're using. For example, a request would look something like `messages.send({body: "Hello"}, "key_randomKey");`.

Is it safe to send keys in requests? In this scenario, the key would be passed as a request property, it would be accessed on the actual backend server for the API and then hashed there and compared to the one in the database (keys are also created on the backend server, not on the server making the request). Is this the wrong approach? I'm wondering how to do this securely.

Comment: What is `messages.send()`?  Is this a webSocket?  An http request?  Are you running these API calls over https with its built-in security?

Comment: @jfriend00 it'll be a method that will make a POST request to the API. In production, HTTPS will be used.

Comment: If you're sending over a properly configured https connection, then the transport is secure and nobody in the middle can see what's in the request so it's OK to put credentials in the request.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you send the key in the authorisation header as bearer token instead.

Use an http Interceptor of some sort in the frontend which will clone every api call and add the authorisation header with the key to it. Then on the backend you can access the token, ideally via a middleware and compare and verify it with the database.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization